# JQuery UI autocomplete scrolable content scrolls up on mouse move

Tags: jquery-ui

I recently implemented JQuery UI autocomplete combobox and everything works fine instead of one bug that I found and can`t manage to find a solution. I can not post my code here as it is company code, but I saw that the issue is visible on the jquery ui Demo page:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight

Now if you type "a" in the input field, you will get a panel with the autocmplete results, which is an `<ul>` element with `<li>` elements inside and because it has a set height, there will be a vertical scroll which is perfect.
Now position your mouse inside the panel with the results, scroll down the list using the mouse wheel and then just move your mouse pointer up back to the input field. 
You will see that the list starts scrolling up.
As many times you do this up and down movement of the mouse pointer, the list will keep going up which is a real problem for my implementation.

I created a regular `<ul>` list with set height and overflow-y property to simulate scrollable ui panel, but I don`t have that issue.

Here is a .gif with the issue and everyone can tested on their page.It happens with Chrome browser

[image: screen gif]

### **UPDATE**

### **!!!SOLVED!!!**

After a lot of playing I found out that the problem is around jquery trying to bring the top element in focus. For some reason it decides that the element that must be in focus is actually the previous element in the list which is not even in the viewport. So focusing to this element cause the menu to "jump" up to the previous element and hence the scrolling up.
I manage to eliminate this issue by changing the margin between the `<li>` elements to 2px (I tried with 1px but it is not enough).

On the actual Jquery demo page I had to increase to 5px to actually work.

You can change the `margin` value in the jqyery-ui.css in the `.ui-menu .ui-menu-item` selector.
This creates enough space between the elements and jquery does not get "confused" which element should be in focus.

[image]

Comment: I think you posted the version backwards? It works as expected in 1.11.1 yet does not work as expected with 1.12.1?

Comment: I see this only happening when a portion of a Menu option is visible and the mouse is then able to come "over" it, giving it `focus`. The focus then  causes that specific element to be viewed fully.

Comment: You can correct for this with CSS. Reduce to `max-height: 96px;`.

Comment: Hi Twisty, so if I use version 1.11.2 everything is OK, but if switch to 1.12.1 the issue is there.

Comment: I also saw the "focus" pattern. But the normal behavior (as can be seen in 1.11.2) is that if the top element is partially visible, will just focus it and bring it entirely in visible are but won`t move up anymore. Rather than in 1.12.1 it keeps going up and up.

Comment: Reducing the max-height to 96px doesn`t help. Scrolling up is keep happening

Comment: Actually the issue persist in both of the versions, just in the older one it doesn`t happen that easy

Comment: I have been unable to replicate it further than bringing the partially viewable item into focus. Which browser and OS are you testing with? I tested your codepen with FireFox 72 on Linux.

Comment: Chome and Windows 7. I tested it on Windows 10 as well. Furthermore I found what was the problem and workaround. I will post it in the original question

Comment: Great. You might consider posting your own answer. Marking it so it's easier to find for others.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your help